# spring authorization server, use exit model for user

Tags: java, spring-security, jackson-modules

I have a model named Member, which implements UserDetails, but got exception when use it login.

environment: JDK 17, spring boot 2.7.0, spring-authorization-server:0.3.0

Member model is like this:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@AllArgsConstructor
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Member implements UserDetails {

    private Long id;

    private String loginAccount;

    private String password;


    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return new ArrayList<>() {
            {
                add(() -> "read");
                add(() -> "write");
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return loginAccount;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Exception i got:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The class with auth.center.domain.Member and name of auth.center.domain.Member is not in the allowlist. If you believe this class is safe to deserialize, please provide an explicit mapping using Jackson annotations or by providing a Mixin. If the serialization is only done by a trusted source, you can also enable default typing. See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/4370 for details
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.JdbcOAuth2AuthorizationService$OAuth2AuthorizationRowMapper.parseMap(JdbcOAuth2AuthorizationService.java:462) ~[spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server-0.3.0.jar:0.3.0]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.JdbcOAuth2AuthorizationService$OAuth2AuthorizationRowMapper.mapRow(JdbcOAuth2AuthorizationService.java:347) ~[spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server-0.3.0.jar:0.3.0]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.JdbcOAuth2AuthorizationService$OAuth2AuthorizationRowMapper.mapRow(JdbcOAuth2AuthorizationService.java:318) ~[spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server-0.3.0.jar:0.3.0]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:94) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:61) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:723) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:651) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:713) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:744) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:799) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.JdbcOAuth2AuthorizationService.findBy(JdbcOAuth2AuthorizationService.java:266) ~[spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server-0.3.0.jar:0.3.0]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.JdbcOAuth2AuthorizationService.findByToken(JdbcOAuth2AuthorizationService.java:251) ~[spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server-0.3.0.jar:0.3.0]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.authentication.CodeVerifierAuthenticator.authenticate(CodeVerifierAuthenticator.java:77) ~[spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server-0.3.0.jar:0.3.0]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.authentication.CodeVerifierAuthenticator.authenticateIfAvailable(CodeVerifierAuthenticator.java:66) ~[spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server-0.3.0.jar:0.3.0]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.authentication.ClientSecretAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(ClientSecretAuthenticationProvider.java:111) ~[spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server-0.3.0.jar:0.3.0]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:182) ~[spring-security-core-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2ClientAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(OAuth2ClientAuthenticationFilter.java:120) ~[spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server-0.3.0.jar:0.3.0]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2AuthorizationServerMetadataEndpointFilter.doFilterInternal(OAuth2AuthorizationServerMetadataEndpointFilter.java:77) ~[spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server-0.3.0.jar:0.3.0]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.NimbusJwkSetEndpointFilter.doFilterInternal(NimbusJwkSetEndpointFilter.java:85) ~[spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server-0.3.0.jar:0.3.0]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.oidc.web.OidcProviderConfigurationEndpointFilter.doFilterInternal(OidcProviderConfigurationEndpointFilter.java:79) ~[spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server-0.3.0.jar:0.3.0]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2AuthorizationEndpointFilter.doFilterInternal(OAuth2AuthorizationEndpointFilter.java:140) ~[spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server-0.3.0.jar:0.3.0]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:117) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.ProviderContextFilter.doFilterInternal(ProviderContextFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server-0.3.0.jar:0.3.0]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:112) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:96) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1743) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The class with auth.center.domain.Member and name of auth.center.domain.Member is not in the allowlist. If you believe this class is safe to deserialize, please provide an explicit mapping using Jackson annotations or by providing a Mixin. If the serialization is only done by a trusted source, you can also enable default typing. See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/4370 for details
    at org.springframework.security.jackson2.SecurityJackson2Modules$AllowlistTypeIdResolver.typeFromId(SecurityJackson2Modules.java:265) ~[spring-security-core-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.TypeDeserializerBase._findDeserializer(TypeDeserializerBase.java:159) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar:2.13.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer._deserializeTypedForId(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:125) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar:2.13.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromObject(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:110) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar:2.13.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromAny(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:213) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar:2.13.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.UntypedObjectDeserializer$Vanilla.deserializeWithType(UntypedObjectDeserializer.java:781) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar:2.13.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.TypeWrappedDeserializer.deserialize(TypeWrappedDeserializer.java:74) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar:2.13.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DefaultDeserializationContext.readRootValue(DefaultDeserializationContext.java:323) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar:2.13.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:4650) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar:2.13.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2831) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar:2.13.3]
    at org.springframework.security.jackson2.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationTokenDeserializer.getPrincipal(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationTokenDeserializer.java:104) ~[spring-security-core-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
    at org.springframework.security.jackson2.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationTokenDeserializer.deserialize(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationTokenDeserializer.java:75) ~[spring-security-core-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
    at org.springframework.security.jackson2.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationTokenDeserializer.deserialize(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationTokenDeserializer.java:51) ~[spring-security-core-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer._deserializeTypedForId(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:144) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar:2.13.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromObject(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:110) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar:2.13.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromAny(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:213) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar:2.13.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.UntypedObjectDeserializer$Vanilla.deserializeWithType(UntypedObjectDeserializer.java:781) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar:2.13.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.TypeWrappedDeserializer.deserialize(TypeWrappedDeserializer.java:74) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar:2.13.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DefaultDeserializationContext.readRootValue(DefaultDeserializationContext.java:323) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar:2.13.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:4650) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar:2.13.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2831) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar:2.13.3]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.jackson2.UnmodifiableMapDeserializer.deserialize(UnmodifiableMapDeserializer.java:52) ~[spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server-0.3.0.jar:0.3.0]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.jackson2.UnmodifiableMapDeserializer.deserialize(UnmodifiableMapDeserializer.java:42) ~[spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server-0.3.0.jar:0.3.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer._deserializeTypedForId(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:144) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar:2.13.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromObject(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:110) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar:2.13.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserializeWithType(MapDeserializer.java:482) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar:2.13.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.TypeWrappedDeserializer.deserialize(TypeWrappedDeserializer.java:74) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar:2.13.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DefaultDeserializationContext.readRootValue(DefaultDeserializationContext.java:323) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar:2.13.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4674) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar:2.13.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3629) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar:2.13.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3612) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar:2.13.3]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.JdbcOAuth2AuthorizationService$OAuth2AuthorizationRowMapper.parseMap(JdbcOAuth2AuthorizationService.java:460) ~[spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server-0.3.0.jar:0.3.0]
    ... 90 common frames omitted
```

My question is:

1. if i wantn't use exist User model, but Member model, how should i add Member model to the Jackson allowlist.
2. I found some demo in the github, but so complicated that i cann't apply them in my application.

Comment: Did you read https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/4370? Di you try some of the solutions?

Comment: I have try, but it dose not work.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following code to your Spring Security configuration class, it should help

```
   @Bean
   public OAuth2AuthorizationService authorizationService(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate, RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository) {
      JdbcOAuth2AuthorizationService jdbcOAuth2AuthorizationService = new JdbcOAuth2AuthorizationService(jdbcTemplate, registeredClientRepository);
      jdbcOAuth2AuthorizationService.setAuthorizationRowMapper(new RowMapper(registeredClientRepository));
      return jdbcOAuth2AuthorizationService;
   }
   
   static class RowMapper extends JdbcOAuth2AuthorizationService.OAuth2AuthorizationRowMapper {
      RowMapper(RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository) {
         super(registeredClientRepository);
         getObjectMapper().addMixIn(Member.class, MemberMixin.class);
      }
   }
   
    @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS)
    @JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY, getterVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE,
          isGetterVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    static class MemberMixin {

       @JsonCreator
       public MemberMixin(@JsonProperty("id") Long id, @JsonProperty("loginAccount") String loginAccount, @JsonProperty("password") String password) {
       }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Andrey Grigoriev that i got insights from his answer.

My final solution is:

1. I change member model
2. Add RowMapper and MemberMixin just like @Andrey Grigoriev past.
3. add MemberDeserializer
4. change MemberMixin annotation

so my code now looks like this:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@AllArgsConstructor
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Member implements UserDetails {

    private Long id;

    private String loginAccount;

    private String password;

    @Transient
    private List<GrantedAuthority> authorities;


    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("read", "write");
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return loginAccount;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

```
 static class RowMapper extends JdbcOAuth2AuthorizationService.OAuth2AuthorizationRowMapper {
        RowMapper(RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository) {
            super(registeredClientRepository);
            getObjectMapper().addMixIn(Member.class, MemberMixin.class);
        }
    }

    @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS)
    @JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY, getterVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE,
            isGetterVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    @JsonDeserialize(using = MemberDeserializer.class)
    static class MemberMixin {
    }
```

```
public class MemberDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Member> {

    @Override
    public Member deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = (ObjectMapper) jsonParser.getCodec();
        JsonNode jsonNode = mapper.readTree(jsonParser);
        Long id = readJsonNode(jsonNode, "id").asLong();
        String loginAccount = readJsonNode(jsonNode, "loginAccount").asText();
        String password = readJsonNode(jsonNode, "password").asText();
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = mapper.readerForListOf(GrantedAuthority.class).readValue(jsonNode.get("authorities"));
        return new Member(id, loginAccount, password, authorities);
    }

    private JsonNode readJsonNode(JsonNode jsonNode, String field) {
        return jsonNode.has(field) ? jsonNode.get(field) : MissingNode.getInstance();
    }
}
```